# Specific 301 redirection

Tags: redirect, opencart

I want to do the follow 301 redirect in .htaccess:
www.mysite.com/products/xxxxxx
to
www.mysite.com/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=xxxxxx

where "xxxxxx" are my products ID's

Please help :)

Comment: you can just switch off seo url in admin panel if you want links to appear like this

Answer (score 0):

```
//301 Redirect Entire Directory
RedirectMatch 301 
www.mysite.com/products/(.*) 
www.mysite.com/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=$1
```